# Как в с# получить имя, тип и значение параметра реестра?

Tags: c#, реестр

[image: Имя, тип и значение параметра реестра Windows]

Я использовал библиотеку Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll, **методы RegistryKey.getValueNames(), RegistryKey.getValueKind() и RegistryKey.getValue** для получения имени, типа и значения параметра соответственно. Вот, что я получил в своем приложении:

[image: Мое приложение]

Как видите, значения на скриншотах отличаются.

При клике на ключ реестра, я вызываю функцию **treeView_registryKeys_AfterSelect**, а в ней такой код:

```
listView_regParData.Items.Clear();

foreach (string valueName in GetRegistryKeyByName(treeView_registryKeys.SelectedNode.Text, regKeysList).GetValueNames())
        {
            var valueData = new string[] { valueName, GetRegistryKeyByName(treeView_registryKeys.SelectedNode.Text, registries).GetValueKind(valueName).ToString(), (string)GetRegistryKeyByName(treeView_registryKeys.SelectedNode.Text, registries).GetValue(valueName) };
            var lvi = new ListViewItem(valueData);
            listView_regParData.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

`GetRegistryKeyByName` - это мой собственный метод для получения ключа реестра типа `RegistryKey` по его `string` имени (второй параметр - список всех проиндексированных ключей).

---

Подскажите какие методы нужно использовать. Будет здорово, если вы предоставите код.

UPD: эти методы правильные.

Comment: Соберите программу явно под x64. Вы скорее всего 32-битный реестр просматриваете.

Comment: И почему у вас `string[]`? Значение ключа реестра не обязательно `string`, о чем и гласит ошибка.

Comment: @aepot, если вы о valueData, то там `string[]`, так как мне важно просто вывести информацию в ListView, без учета ее типа данных. При добавлении данных в массив я конвентирую эти значения в `string`. Не понял зачем собирать программу под x64. Не думаю, что моя ошибка связана именно с этим.

Comment: Начните с устранения ошибки: _Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Int32" к типу "System.String_. Например, используйте `object`.

Comment: @hot_penguin ну тогда о чем вы спрашиваете, если вы все знаете лучше. И да, начните с того, что перевод `int` в `string` делается вот так `intValue.ToString()`, а не `(string)intValue`. По поводу 64 бит - [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=netframework-4.8). Без явного указания RegistryView вы получаете версию реестра согласно разрядности вашего приложения, и эти версии (внезапно) разные.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для того, чтобы вывести данные в ListView мне нужен `string`, а не `object`. Не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. Я также не понимаю, на что именно ругается c#, так как эта ошибка появляется не всегда, а только при нажатии на определенные ключи реестра.

Comment: Забудьте на время про ListView, забудьте про GUI. Для начала просто добейтесь получения данных из реестра. Число - это не строка - что не понятно в этой ошибке?

Comment: Тут проблема, насколько я понимаю, связана именно с использованием неправильных методов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие методы мне необходимо использовать, чтобы получить данные, как на первом скриншоте. У меня проблема A, поэтому я пока не хочу решать проблему B (я про разрядность).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov то, что число это не строка понятно. Ошибка возникает довольно редко (при нажатии на некоторые ключи реестра в TreeView). И каждый раз ошибка разная. Вот только что я покликал около 30 ключей и ошибка не появилась ни разу. Но меня смущает то, что в моем приложении и в редакторе реестра Windows **имя, тип и значение** отличаются. Соответственно скорее всего я использую **неверные методы**. Моя цель - получить верные данные. Поэтому я считаю странным решать проблемы, возникающие при использовании неверных методов - возможно, при использовании верных, они даже не появятся.

Comment: Я использовал эти методы: **RegistryKey.getValueNames(), RegistryKey.getValueKind() и RegistryKey.getValue**. Если вы разбираетесь в них, то, пожалуйста, подскажите, верные ли они, и какие использовать вместо них, если нет.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за цитирование. Я явно описал то, что я хочу увидеть (первый скриншот), а также минимальный код.

Comment: `У меня проблема A, поэтому я пока не хочу решать проблему B` У вас [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/213987): у меня проблема при забивании гвоздей микроскопом, но я не планирую заниматься проблемой изучения молотка.

Comment: _Я явно описал ... минимальный код_ - нет, вы привели код, который работает с ListView. А у вас проблема с кодом который работает с реестром. Но его вы почему-то не показываете.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov там нет проблемы, методы правильные. Просто эти методы возвращали информацию о параметре немного в другом виде, нежели в приложении реестра Windows и я думал, что эт ошибка. А оказалось их можно изменить и сделать такими же, как и в приложении реестра Windows, _aepot_ ответил и показал, как это сделать. Проблема решена. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь только в названиях типов и отображении их в вашем редакторе, то берем перечисление `RegistryValueKind` ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=netframework-4.8)), и переписываем как нам надо.

```cs
public enum RegistryValueKindNative
{
    NONE = -1,
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    REG_SZ = 1,
    REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2,
    REG_BINARY = 3,
    REG_DWORD = 4,
    REG_MULTI_SZ = 7,
    REG_QWORD = 11
}
```

Далее не особо сложно вывести это в строку как душе угодно.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (RegistryKey root = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Console"))
    {
        foreach (string name in root.GetValueNames().OrderBy(x => x))
        {
            object value = root.GetValue(name);
            RegistryValueKind kind = root.GetValueKind(name);
            string valueString = (kind == RegistryValueKind.DWord) ? $"0x{((int)value).ToString("X2").ToLower().PadLeft(8,'0')} ({(uint)(int)value})" : value.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine($"{name, -25} {(RegistryValueKindNative)kind, -13} {valueString}");
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```cs
ColorTable00              REG_DWORD     0x000c0c0c (789516)
ColorTable01              REG_DWORD     0x00da3700 (14300928)
ColorTable02              REG_DWORD     0x000ea113 (958739)
ColorTable03              REG_DWORD     0x00dd963a (14521914)
ColorTable04              REG_DWORD     0x001f0fc5 (2035653)
ColorTable05              REG_DWORD     0x00981788 (9967496)
ColorTable06              REG_DWORD     0x00009cc1 (40129)
ColorTable07              REG_DWORD     0x00cccccc (13421772)
ColorTable08              REG_DWORD     0x00767676 (7763574)
ColorTable09              REG_DWORD     0x00ff783b (16742459)
ColorTable10              REG_DWORD     0x000cc616 (837142)
ColorTable11              REG_DWORD     0x00d6d661 (14079585)
ColorTable12              REG_DWORD     0x005648e7 (5654759)
ColorTable13              REG_DWORD     0x009e00b4 (10354868)
ColorTable14              REG_DWORD     0x00a5f1f9 (10875385)
ColorTable15              REG_DWORD     0x00f2f2f2 (15921906)
CtrlKeyShortcutsDisabled  REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
CurrentPage               REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
CursorColor               REG_DWORD     0xffffffff (4294967295)
CursorSize                REG_DWORD     0x00000019 (25)
DefaultBackground         REG_DWORD     0xffffffff (4294967295)
DefaultForeground         REG_DWORD     0xffffffff (4294967295)
EnableColorSelection      REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
ExtendedEditKey           REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
ExtendedEditKeyCustom     REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
FaceName                  REG_SZ        __DefaultTTFont__
FilterOnPaste             REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
FontFamily                REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
FontSize                  REG_DWORD     0x00100000 (1048576)
FontWeight                REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
ForceV2                   REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
FullScreen                REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
HistoryBufferSize         REG_DWORD     0x00000032 (50)
HistoryNoDup              REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
InsertMode                REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
LineSelection             REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
LineWrap                  REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
LoadConIme                REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
NumberOfHistoryBuffers    REG_DWORD     0x00000004 (4)
PopupColors               REG_DWORD     0x000000f5 (245)
QuickEdit                 REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
ScreenBufferSize          REG_DWORD     0x23290078 (589889656)
ScreenColors              REG_DWORD     0x00000007 (7)
ScrollScale               REG_DWORD     0x00000001 (1)
TerminalScrolling         REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
TrimLeadingZeros          REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
WindowAlpha               REG_DWORD     0x000000ff (255)
WindowSize                REG_DWORD     0x001e0078 (1966200)
WordDelimiters            REG_DWORD     0x00000000 (0)
```

Как видите, дело не в том, что C# чего-то не может...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное!