# Как использовать comboBox, чтобы передать переменную типа RegistryValueKind для метода RegistryKey.SetValue()?

Tags: c#, реестр

У меня есть ArrayList:

```
static public ArrayList regValueKindsList = new ArrayList();
```

Я его заполняю типами значений (параметров):

```
        Reg.regValueKindsList.Add("REG_SZ");
        Reg.regValueKindsList.Add("REG_EXPAND_SZ");
        Reg.regValueKindsList.Add("REG_BINARY");
        Reg.regValueKindsList.Add("REG_DWORD");
        Reg.regValueKindsList.Add("REG_MULTI_SZ");
        Reg.regValueKindsList.Add("REG_QWORD");
```

Затем этот список передается в comboBox:

```
comboBox_parData.DataSource = Reg.regValueKindsList;
```

В программе при создании параметра я вызываю эту форму:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь выбираю тип параметра из comboBox, а также имя и значение.

При нажатии на кнопку вся эта информация передается в поля отдельного класса (для передачи информации между формами):

```
                Data.newParName = textBox_parName.Text;
                Data.newParType = (RegistryValueKind)comboBox_parData.SelectedItem; 
                Data.newParValue = textBox_parValue.Text;
```

Вот как я создал эти поля:

```
    public static RegistryValueKind newParType { get; set; }
    public static string newParName { get; set; }
    public static string newParValue { get; set; }
```

Обратите внимание на приведение типов; В comboBox используется тип object (так как данные получены из ListArray), а для метода .SetValue() нужен тип RegistryValueKind.

А затем эти переменные используются для создания нового параметра:

```
selRegKeyOpened.SetValue(Data.newParName, Data.newParValue, Data.newParType);
```

Возникает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можете посоветовать? Мне главное с помощью формы создать параметр (имя, тип, значение), не обязательно фиксить мой способ, если есть принципиально другие идеи, то хорошо.

Comment: 1) `ArrayList` поменяйте на `List<string>`, так проще будет. 2) `Data.newParType = (RegistryValueKind)Enum.Parse(typeof(RegistryValueKindNative), comboBox_parData.SelectedItem, true);`

Comment: @aepot 1) Заменил. 2) Написал так 'Data.newParType = (RegistryValueKind)Enum.Parse(typeof(Reg.RegistryValueKindNative), comboBox_parData.SelectedItem.ToString(), true);' (Visual Studio сказала, что object необходимо сконвертировать в string). Программа висит при создании параметра и не создает его

Comment: Вытащите `enum` из класса, никогда не прячьте типы в классах. Пусть он будет отдельно, рядом с классом, а не внутри. И какой там объект в строку надо преобразовать? Какой точный текст исключения. И программа не висит, это студия ее морощит, когда исключение возникает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю, как вам удается ловить ошибки на ровном месте, но у меня получилось вот так

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // заполняю список из перечисления с помощью Enum.GetValues и Linq
        List<string> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RegistryValueKindNative)).Cast<RegistryValueKindNative>().Where(x => x > 0).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
        comboBox1.DataSource = values;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryValueKind kind = (RegistryValueKind)Enum.Parse(typeof(RegistryValueKindNative), comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(kind.ToString());
    }
}

public enum RegistryValueKindNative
{
    NONE = -1,
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    REG_SZ = 1,
    REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2,
    REG_BINARY = 3,
    REG_DWORD = 4,
    REG_MULTI_SZ = 7,
    REG_QWORD = 11
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: KingNative а в вопросе King. Понятно что парсит.

Comment: @AzizUmarov эта история началась [раньше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208652/373567). Перечисление у автора в проекте есть, он просто забыл про него, когда писал этот вопрос. :)

Comment: Ясно + от меня. Я не в курсе просто. Лишь указал как парсить enum

Comment: @AzizUmarov ваш ответ верный по сути, правда `SelectedItem` все же правильнее здесь. `SelectedValue` надо там, где класс со свойствами и вы вяжете айтем комбобокса через `ValueMember` к одному из свойств класса, вот тогда Item = экземпляр, а Value = нужное свойство. А здесь скорее всего все равно, но я не проверял.

Comment: Спорить не стану смысла не вижу. Просто я не имею привычки использовать текст итемы и прочее когда есть валуе. В любом случае проверять мне м телефона не очень приятно

Comment: @AzizUmarov так я и не спорю, проверил, `SelectedValue` здесь тоже работает, так что оба варианта верные. Плюсик уже стоит.

Comment: @aepot вот, что я получаю: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Не удалось выполнить запись в раздел реестра."

Comment: @aepot вот на этой строчке ошибка: `selRegKeyOpened.SetValue(Data.newParName, Data.newParValue, Data.newParType);`

Comment: @hot_penguin `UnauthorizedAccessException` - догадайтесь, с чем это связано. Нет прав для записи в реестр. Помните я вам говорил про 32-битную и 64-битную версию реестра? Оно может здесь повлиять, а еще может повлиять то, что вам нужно запустить приложение от имени администратора, а для отладки - саму студию надо так запустить. Но в любом случае эта ошибка не относится к вашему вопросу и моему ответу.

Answer (score 1):

Так попробуйте

```
(RegistryValueKind) Enum.Parse(typeof(RegistryValueKind), comboBox_parData.SelectedValue, true);
```

Comment: [Ошибка еще до запуска программы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6TS3.png)

Comment: Проблема по сути у вас стринги а вы хотите получить enum. А enum это целое число

Comment: По сути достаточно указать числа которые соответствует вашим строкам

Comment: Попробуйте. ToString

Comment: [Ошибка уже после запуска программы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6TS3.png)

Comment: Вам нужно правильно указать строки чтоб parse принимало значения

Comment: @hot_penguin `RegistryValueKindNative` же, если это [то, о чем я думаю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208652/373567). Вы перепутали перечисление. :) `(RegistryValueKind)Enum.Parse(typeof(RegistryValueKindNative), comboBox_parData.SelectedValue, true);`

Comment: @aepot да не, это код у AzizUmarov я скопировал. Там не было RegistryValueKindNative. Да и с этим тоже не работает (программа при создании параметра висит).

Comment: @hot_penguin И все-таки наверно `SelectedItem`, а не `SelectedValue`.

Comment: Selected Item это comboboxItem просто

Comment: Я про100 не за компом Нето подкинул вариант

Comment: [Да нет же](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ComboBox_SelectedItem).

Comment: Да не суть стринги все равно не парсит