# Не корректная запись в реестр C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, реестр

Приложение собрано в x64 с админ правами.

При попытке записи в реестр данного параметра `Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile").SetValue("NetworkThrottlingIndex", 0xffffffff);`

В реестр вписывается не каретное значение в формате RED_SZ, а не REG_DWORD со значением 4294967295

Comment: `.SetValue("NetworkThrottlingIndex", 0xffffffff, RegistryValueKind.DWord)` - [документация же есть](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_SetValue_System_String_System_Object_Microsoft_Win32_RegistryValueKind_).

Comment: Вот еще вам для разогрева https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208652/373567

Comment: .SetValue("NetworkThrottlingIndex", 0xffffffff, RegistryValueKind.DWord) - выдает ошибку после этого я уже попробовал так

Comment: Смотрите в документацию. Если ключ уже создан, он не пересоздастся. И вообще только вам известно, что там за ошибка.

Comment: System.ArgumentException: "Тип объекта значения совпадает с заданным RegistryValueKind либо объект не может быть корректно преобразован."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_SetValue_System_String_System_Object_), смотрите в пример кода.

> Numeric values that cannot be interpreted as DWord (int) values are stored as strings.

То есть решение будет такое

```cs
Registry.LocalMachine
    .CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile")
    .SetValue("NetworkThrottlingIndex", unchecked((int)0xffffffff));
```

Comment: Выдает это -- Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка CS0221 Постоянное значение "4294967295" не может быть преобразовано в "int" (для переопределения используйте синтаксис "unchecked"). kicklag C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\kicklag\Form1.cs 186 Активные

Comment: @Forum4anin ну что написано, то и надо сделать, обновил ответ.

Comment: @Forum4anin лайфхак: `unchecked((int)0xffffffff)` можно заменить просто на `-1`.