# Как сделать экспорт раздела реестра в MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, реестр

Использую след код для сохранения в файле

```
using RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MortalCombat");
//Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/e " + fileName+" " + reg.ToString());
Process.Start("regedit.exe", $"/e File.reg {reg}");
```

Я хочу данные раздела реестра сохранить в байтовый массив (`byte array`)

```
using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
```

Как мне реализовать бэкап разделов реестра, не записывая на диск сохранить в памяти?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15410097/12888024 экспортируйте в файл, оттуда можете загрузить текст куда хотите.

Comment: либо можно руками перебрать все ключи https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1208652/373567 и записать в свою структуру данных